# Storing data and using it to choose an option

Tags: batch-file

How would I store data in a text document and have my batch file use it? I have a menu that goes off of what is stored in a text document and can be change within the batch file. I have a problem with it changing though.

```
:start
for /f "Delims=" %%a in (C:\Users\Second\Documents\Folder\color.txt) do (
    set colorset=%%a
    )
if %colorset%==1 goto white
if %colorset%==2 goto red
if %colorset%==3 goto blue
if %colorset%==4 goto yellow
if %colorset%==5 goto gray
if %colorset%==6 goto green
if %colorset%==7 goto purple
goto white
:yellow
set /a color = 4
echo %color% > color.txt
```

I have a number saved in "color.txt" but it won't change for me when i go to change it in the batch file. I want it so when I change it in the batch file and exit, it will stay as the color I changed it to when I reopen it. Can anyone help?

Comment: `echo %color% > color.txt` saves color value to *color.txt* in whatever directory that happens to be the current directory, whereas the original *color.txt* is located at `C:\Users\Second\Documents\Folder`. Try `echo %color% > "C:\Users\Second\Documents\Folder\color.txt"`. And as a best practice try to get the habit of putting file and directory paths between quotes: `for /f "UseBackq Delims=" %%a in ("C:\Users\Second\Documents\Folder\color.txt") do ...`

Comment: The main problem is that the path of the `C:\Users\Second\Documents\Folder\color.txt` input file is different from the `color.txt` output one; however, there are other problem here. If the input color is `4` your logic execute a `goto yellow` where a `set /a color = 4` is set, that is, the input and output colors _are the same_...

Comment: BTW in your code you have **not** "a menu" because nothing is presented in the screen for user selection...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now have a look at this simple method:

```
@echo off
set "colorfile=D:\color.txt"
if exist "%colorfile%" call :colorset
echo 0 = Black
echo 1 = Blue
echo 2 = Green
echo 3 = Aqua
echo 4 = Red
echo 5 = Purple
echo 6 = Yellow
echo 7 = White
set /p "colorselect=Select a Color number or Press <Enter> leave Current: "
if %colorselect% GEQ 0 echo %colorselect% > "%colorfile%" || call :colorset
:colorset
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%colorfile%") do color %%a
```

First we set a permanent file with path, so we do not have to set it across the file. Then check if the path and file `color.txt` exists, if it does, set the color to the number in the file, then prompt user if he wants to use another color, or leave current.

The file will startup each time with the color found in the file, which can be manipulated from the batch by overwriting it if you change a new color.
If however `color.txt` does not exist, it will prompt for you to choose a color and then it will set the color and echo it to the file.

Comment: In the `set /a color = 4` command the spaces around `=` will _never_ cause issues (because the `/a` switch is included). Besides, the code example does **not** input a new color _from the user_ (it just directly change the input color for an output one) nor change the color _in the screen_. This question is about _"storing data and using it"_, **not** about changing colors...

Comment: @Aacini I am storing data and using it. `if %colorselect% GEQ 0 echo %colorselect% > "%colorfile%"  || call :colorset` You are correct on the `set /a` I forgot about the /a switch.